# Convert .asc type to .csv or .json

Tags: gdal, convert, csv, json

I have an `asc` type file which describes measurements of a gas across an area at 1km square resolution. It looks like this:

````
NCols 1725
NRows 2175
xllcorner -224131.189661
yllcorner 4892726.61578
cellsize 1000.0
NODATA_value -1.0
-0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 -0 etc```

I can visualise this raster format in QGIS:

[![Gas at 1km square resolution][1]][1]

I now want to convert this to a vector form.

Ultimately I wish to convert this to a `csv` or `json` type file that contains the bounds for each 1km square section and the associated metric being visualised in the raster format. 

I have tried to convert from raster to vector using `gdal` as an intermediate step in the right direction:

`gdal_polygonize.py sample_file.asc`
    
However, this resulted in:

    "/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Programs/gdal_polygonize.py", line 186, in 
        dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = srs )
        AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateLayer'

Is there a more direct path for doing this? 

Edit. Running `gdalinfo file_name` presents:

    Driver: AAIGrid/Arc/Info ASCII Grid
    Files: file.asc
    Size is 1725, 2175
    Coordinate System is `'
    Origin = (-224131.189661000011256,7067726.615779999643564)
    Pixel Size = (1000.000000000000000,-1000.000000000000000)
    Corner Coordinates:
    Upper Left  ( -224131.190, 7067726.616)
    Lower Left  ( -224131.190, 4892726.616)
    Upper Right ( 1500868.810, 7067726.616)
    Lower Right ( 1500868.810, 4892726.616)
    Center      (  638368.810, 5980226.616)
    Band 1 Block=1725x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
      NoData Value=-1
````

From this I can calculate the bounds of each idinvidual pixel simply enough. However, the issue of taking the actual data field itself persists.

Answer (score 0):

The Python error comes because the command was given without a compulsory parameter for the output file.

Now, six years later, the gdal_polygonize.py script gives a proper error message:

```
gdal_polygonize test.tif
usage: gdal_polygonize.py [-h] [-q] [-8] [-o [name=value ...]] [-mask filename] [-nomask]
                          [-b band] [-of ogr_format]
                          src_filename dst_filename [dst_layername] [dst_fieldname]
gdal_polygonize.py: error: the following arguments are required: dst_filename
```